# Разработать shell-процедуру

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Помогите, пожалуйста, вот задание:

- Вводит последовательность из N слов и подсчитывает в каждом введенном слове число символов. Если число символов больше М, то слово выводится на экран. Значения N и М передаются в качестве параметров.

  ```
    read N M
    echo $N $M
    while [ "$N" != 0 ]
    do
    read text
    echo $text
    awk '{if (length($0) > 15) print $0}'
    done
  ```

Сделал такой код, в проверке символов вместо 15 должен быть параметр M, но не получается так сделать... А и получается, что у меня проверяет длину строки, а не кол-во символов в слове + выводит именно строку, а не слова

Comment: Добрый день, с чем именно у вас проблема? Покажите ваш код

Comment: Добрый день, дополнил тему

Comment: То что вы написали, очень странный набор команд, видимо вы не изучили азы данного скриптового языка? Для начала вам следует почитать документацию и изучить примеры, например: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/shell_scripting.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#имя процедуры может быть любым
name_procedure() {
#проверяем переменные
    fullText="${1:?Не передан текст для проверки}"
    num=${2:?Не передано число символов}
#цикл по тексту
    for text in $fullText; do
#${#...} - выводит количество символов в переменной
# -gt больше, -ge больше или равно, -eq равно, -lt меньше, -le меньше или равно, -ne не равно
       [[ ${#text} -gt ${num} ]] && echo $text
    done
}
```

Вызов:

```
name_procedure "текст для валидации, обязательно в кавычках, либо экранируем пробелы" 7
```

Вывод:

```txt
валидации,
обязательно
кавычках,
экранируем
```

Comment: спасибо, но почему-то не запускается или я что-то не так делаю

Comment: @wade сначала объявляется функция, вывода никакого не будет, потом вызывается с передачей параметров

Comment: мне пишет: строка 2: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «$'{\r'»

Comment: У вас видимо при копировании появилась последовательность переносов `\r\n` откройте в notepad++ и справа внизу переключите с `Windows CR LF` на `Unix LF`, если же вы этот скрипт храните в файловой системе, то просто удалите переносы из него с помощью командной строки `sed -i 's/\r//' /путь к скрипту`

Comment: Либо можете просто скопировать функцию и вставить в терминал: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFcQA.png

Comment: благодарю за помощь, теперь всё заработало.

Comment: @wade, если ответ решает вашу проблему, то вы можете отметить его как верный, делается это слева от вопроса.